# VBA Calculations to add columns based on one columns answer

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code so far to subtract one column from another, but then need to take that result and if `D` is **negative** then `F = D + F` else `E = E + D`

```
  Sub PopCol()
      Range("D3:D19").Formula = "=RC[-1]-RC[-2]"  'D=C-B
```

I'm Lost! Been trying different formats for range in this and have had no luck-HELP!

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub PopCol()
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range

    Set rng = Range("D3:D19")

    rng.Formula = "=RC[-1]-RC[-2]"

    For Each aCell In rng
        Select Case aCell.Value

        Case Is < 0 '<~~ If value in D is negative
            '~~>  F = F + D
            aCell.Offset(, 2).Value = aCell.Offset(, 2).Value + aCell.Value
        Case Else
            '~~>  E = E + D
            aCell.Offset(, 1).Value = aCell.Offset(, 1).Value + aCell.Value
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Fantastic! I couldn't think of one way to word this and here are two different formats! I think I prefer the use of Case(s) but mostly because this just a component of a larger code I need to write. Thank you for showing me the way!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
  Sub PopCol()
    For i = 3 To 19
        Range("D" & i) = CLng(Range("C" & i) - Range("B" & i))
        If (Range("D" & i) < 0) Then
            Range("F" & i) = Range("D" & i) + Range("F" & i)
        Else
            Range("E" & i) = Range("E" & i) + Range("D" & i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great - I hate that I just don't know how to word things to get them done!